# Pandas pivot_table dropping columns that are not being used for pivoting

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

`pivot_table` is dropping columns that are NOT being pivoted.

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id   FieldTitle  Value  number
1     fname       aaa    12
2     lname       bbb    12
```

When I run this line of code:

```
pivoted_df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Id', columns='FieldTitle', values='Value', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

The df that is left is:

```
fname    lname
aaa        bbb
```

Why is pivot causing the other columns to disappear and how do I fix it?

The df should look like this:

```
id   fname  lname  number
1     aaa    bbb    12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
values=['Value', 'number']
```

Or if you want all possible columns, don't pass `values` at all.

Comment: number is just a made up field that I used in the example. this data set has roughly 500 other columns so I am not sure what to put in for number. – RustyShackleford just now

Comment: @RustyShackleford: Oh, then simply don't pass `values` at all.

Comment: Do you mean remove the variable `values` or the word `value` in brackets?

Comment: @RustyShackleford: Which of those options makes sense?  Why not try both and see?